# Cannot read special characters with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc, utf-8

I'm having problem reading UTF-8 data from MySQL database by using MySQL Connector v. 8.0.19. Scandic letters, such as "äö" are replaced with unknown characters. I already made sure the database and its tables and columns are using `utf8mb4`. Then I added `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to JDBC connection string, but the outcome is still unexpected. I'm running MySQL CE v. 8 in a Docker container. I can see the scandic letters fine when I run the `SELECT` queries in a command-line.

Comment: Where are you printing the output?

Comment: I’m printing the output from the getter right after the value is set from `ResultSet`.

Comment: If you are printing to System.out, then ensure it is using UTF-8: `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");` - and then: `out.println("读写汉字");`. Better yet, use `import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of "UTF-8". I'm sure this is answered in other SO questions but cannot find a good example right now.

Comment: I’m developing Rest API with Spring Boot and I saw this problem first time from JSON response (`ResponseEntity`). I did the printing with logger just to see where the problem is originating. Is this behavior normal from JDBC and what would be the best solution?

Comment: Select HEX(col) so we can see what was stored.  What do you mean by "unknown characters"?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I just tried, what @andrewjames suggested, but my "äö" still gets replaced with "Ã¤" characters. I printed the result directly from `ResultSet`. What comes to `SELECT HEX(col_name)`, here is one problematic HEX string: "596C6569736CC383C2A4C383C2A46BC383C2A47269". When I use online converter, even that cannot show the value correctly. Collation for this table seems to be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and the same applies to columns.

Comment: And when I enter to MySQL command-line with parameter `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` I cannot see the values correctly anymore. I cannot even type scandic letters in MySQL command-line. I used SQL script to create the schema. The schema was written in Visual Studio Code and there seems to be UTF-8 enabled.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and make sure to also show what the actual value is supposed to be of that hex-value, that way it is possible to identify actually which character set is used to store your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by passing `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` to MySQL command-line before creating the schema from a separate file. I could add this option to MySQL server configuration as a default.